# How to put the slider-counter in the middle of the buttons?

Tags: html, owl-carousel

I am using the owl.carousel.js plugin for the content slide. The slider is working but I need slider-counter in the center.

I am getting the output like this.

[image: demo2]

I need output like this.

[image: demo]

But still not able to display the slider-counter in the center. Can you help me where I am wrong?

style.css

```
<style>
     .owl-carousel {
         position: relative;
     }
    .owl-theme .owl-nav {
        float: left;
    }
    .owl-carousel .owl-prev,
    .owl-carousel .owl-next {
        width: 90px;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 10px !important;
    }
    .slider-counter {
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
</style>
```

html (blade)

```
@if(count($videos) > 0)
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="text-white bg-purple p-3">Videos</h5>
        <div class="carousel-wrapper">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-videos">
                @foreach($videos as $video)
                    <div class="item mb-5" data-dot="<span>{{ $video->id }}</span>">
                        <a class="card border-0 text-decoration-none text-purple" href="{{ $video->play() }}">
                            <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$section->image) }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ $section->title }}" title="{{ $section->title }}">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="h5 card-title">{{ $video->title }}</h5>
                                <div class="card-text">{!! str()->limit($video->body, 20) !!}</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="slider-counter slider-counter3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.owl-videos').owlCarousel({
            rtl:true,
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            dots: true,
            nav:true,
            items: 1,
            navText: [
                "<div class='nav-button owl-prev'><i class='fa-solid fa-angle-right'></i><span> prev </span></div>",
                "<div class='nav-button owl-next'><span> next </span><i class='fa-solid fa-angle-left'></i></div>"
            ],
            responsiveClass:true,
            onInitialized: counter3,
            onChanged: counter3,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:5
                }
            }
        });
    });
    function counter3(event) {
        if (!event.namespace) {
            return;
        }
        var slides = event.relatedTarget;
        $('.slider-counter3').text(slides.relative(slides.current()) + 1 + ' of ' + slides.items().length);
        console.log(slides.current())
    }
</script>
```